# Spring Security authentication.getauthorities() is always empty, Login is not fetching authorities of authenticated user

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple login/registration App. Where I have

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_user")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class AppUser extends AbstractAuditable<AppUser, Long> implements UserDetails {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(
            cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE},
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<UserRole> authorities;

    public AppUser(){
        super();
        this.authorities = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    }

    public AppUser(String username, String password, Set<UserRole> authorities) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(Set<UserRole> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return this.authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
        AppUser appUser = (AppUser) o;
        return Objects.equals(username, appUser.username) && Objects.equals(password, appUser.password) && Objects.equals(authorities, appUser.authorities);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), username, password, authorities);
    }
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_role")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class UserRole extends AbstractAuditable<AppUser, Long> implements GrantedAuthority {

    private String authority;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authorities")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<AppUser> appUsers = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public Set<AppUser> getAppUsers() {
        return appUsers;
    }

    public void setAppUsers(Set<AppUser> appUsers) {
        this.appUsers = appUsers;
    }

    public UserRole(){
        super();
    }

    public UserRole(String authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return this.authority;
    }

    public void setAuthority(String authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
        UserRole userRole = (UserRole) o;
        return Objects.equals(authority, userRole.authority) && Objects.equals(appUsers, userRole.appUsers);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), authority, appUsers);
    }
}
```

Token service goes

```
@Service
public class TokenService {

    private final JwtEncoder jwtEncoder;

    private final JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

    public TokenService(JwtEncoder jwtEncoder, JwtDecoder jwtDecoder) {
        this.jwtEncoder = jwtEncoder;
        this.jwtDecoder = jwtDecoder;
    }

    public String generateJwt(Authentication authentication){

        // Get current time
        var now = Instant.now();

        var scope = authentication.getAuthorities()
                .stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

        System.out.println("TOKEN_SERVICE -> " + scope); // This line 'scope' contains nothing

        var claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
                .issuer("self")
                .issuedAt(now)
                .subject(authentication.getName())
                .claim("roles", scope)
                .build();

        return jwtEncoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claims)).getTokenValue();
    }
}
```

finally

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AuthService {

    private final AppUserRepository appUserRepository;

    private final UserRoleRepository userRoleRepository;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private final TokenService tokenService;

    public AuthService(
            AppUserRepository appUserRepository,
            UserRoleRepository userRoleRepository,
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
            AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
            TokenService tokenService
    ) {
        this.appUserRepository = appUserRepository;
        this.userRoleRepository = userRoleRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.tokenService = tokenService;
    }

    public AppUser registerUser(String username, String password){

        // Encode password
        var encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);

        // GET ROLES
        var userRole = userRoleRepository.findByAuthority("USER").orElseThrow(
                () -> new EntityNotFoundException("Invalid role")
        );

        var userRoles = new LinkedHashSet<UserRole>();
        userRoles.add(userRole);

        return appUserRepository.save(
                new AppUser(username,encodedPassword, userRoles)
        );

    }

    public LoginResponseDTO login(String username, String password){

        try {
            var auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password)
            );

            var token = tokenService.generateJwt(auth);
            var appUser = appUserRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(
                    () -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid user")
            );

            System.out.println("Current Authorities: " + appUser.getAuthorities().toString() );

            return new LoginResponseDTO(appUser, token);
        } catch (AuthenticationException e){
            return new LoginResponseDTO(null, "");
        }
    }
}
```

Now with Security configuration bellow:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private static final String BASE_PATH = "/api/v1";

    private final RSAKeyProperties keys;

    public SecurityConfiguration(RSAKeyProperties keys) {
        this.keys = keys;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        // FIX for error -> Refused to display 'http://localhost:8080/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
        http.headers( headers ->
            headers.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::sameOrigin)
        );

        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests( auths -> {
                   auths
                           .requestMatchers(antMatcher(BASE_PATH +"/auth/**")).permitAll()
                           .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll()
                           .requestMatchers(antMatcher(BASE_PATH +"/admin/**")).hasRole("ADMIN")
                           .requestMatchers(antMatcher(BASE_PATH +"/user/**")).hasRole("USER")
                           .anyRequest().authenticated();
                });
        // Set OAuth2
        http.oauth2ResourceServer(
                resourceServerConfigurer -> {
                    resourceServerConfigurer.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults());
                }
        ).sessionManagement(
                sessionManagementConfigurer -> {
                    sessionManagementConfigurer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
                }
        );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(UserDetailsService userDetailsService){
        var authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider(passwordEncoder());
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return new ProviderManager(authProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder("mysecret", 8, 320000, PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(){
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(keys.getRsaPublicKey()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder(){
        JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(keys.getRsaPublicKey()).privateKey(keys.getRsaPrivateKey()).build();
        JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));

        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter(){
        var jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");

        var jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);

        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }
}
```

When I register a user at `/register` endpoint:

[image: Register response with authorities]

but when I login at `/login` endpoint you can see:

[image: Login response without authorities]

For reference [GitHub Link](https://github.com/arshadalisoomro/auth) for project,

This is the issue when I login. Can you suggest a solution to this, any help is highly appreciated. Thanks